# Faster alternative to .load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using

```
    $('.class').load(location.href+" .class>*","");
```

to refresh a div's contents but it's pretty slow. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: If that's slow, it's going to be 1) your network, 2) slow page generation from the server, or 3) the response is so huge that it's taking jQuery a long time to parse out the portion you want. 1) and 2) are far more likely than 3). Not really anything you can do to make it faster at the jQuery level.

Comment: Yes, you could modify `location.href` to only return the content needed by ajax rather than everything so that you don't need to do any filtering. but, it likely won't be that much faster.